# How to change from "would rather" to "would prefer"?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

Let see [this sentence](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would-rather-would-sooner):

**She would rather have spent the money on a holiday.** (The money wasn’t spent on a holiday.)

Is this sentence "**She would prefer to have spent the money on a holiday.**" the same as the above?

**I’d rather you hadn’t rung me at work.**

Is this sentence "**I'd prefer you not to have spent the money on a holiday.**" the same as the above?

[Source](http://www.grammarbank.com/would-rather-would-prefer.html)

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.  What's the purpose of the sentence about the phone call? And what do you mean by "the same"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they're essentially the same. The first simply says that she'd spent the money on holiday if she could have, while the latter simply says that she'd choose to spend her money on holiday if it were here choice; both statements essentially say she'd choose to pay for a vacation if it were an option. They're two ways of saying the same thing.